# Error: Presto server is still initializing

Tags: presto

I am using presto-cli command on AWS EMR. I am passing a file (-f option) with multiple queries to execute in presto. After it executes the first query, it fails while at second  query. The error message is:

> Error running command: Error starting query at
>   http://localhost:8889/v1/statement returned an invalid response:
>   JsonResponse{statusCode=500, statusMessage=Internal Server Error,
>   headers={Content-Length=[5419], Date=[Mon, 21 May 2018 10:38:16 GMT],
>   Content-Type=[text/plain]}, hasValue=false, value=null} [Error:
>   com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Presto server is still
>   initializing

If presto was on while executing the first query why it is unable to execute the second and later ones?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Presto Server has crashed after executing the first query and it got restarted just after the crash.

Please find the Presto `server.log` and try to see if there is anything which could point the culprit of the crash.

Comment: @Ankit Mahajan did you find out what was issue, iam facing similar issue